# How do I return a boolean value?

Tags: swift, boolean

So I have a class with the method `isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool`. This should return `true` if a discount can be applied based on the supplied list of product ids (i.e. a product must be matched to an offer) and the product IDs are 901 and 902.

I have attempted it but uncertain if done correctly or if there is a better way.

thanks in advance!

```
class HalfPriceOffer :Offer {

    init(){
        super.init(name: "Half Price on Wine")
        applicableProductIds = [901,902];
    }

    override func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
        //should return true if a dicount can be applied based on the supplied list of product ids (i.e. a product must be matched to an offer)

        if true == 901 {
            return true
        }
        if true == 902 {
            return true
        }

        else {

            return false

        }
    }
}
```

ShoppingItem

```
class ShoppingItem {

    var name :String
    var priceInPence :Int
    var productId :Int

    init(name:String, price:Int, productId:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.priceInPence = price
        self.productId = productId
    }
}
```

Comment: `true == 901` is likely not what you mean.  maybe `productId == 901` ??

Comment: @danh I get an error when I type anything else.

Comment: How is `ShoppingItem` defined?

Comment: @vacawama Hi, I've edited my post please see the shoppingitem.

Comment: @vacawama oops, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the items in your list and test if the item's `productId` is in the list of `applicableProductIds` using the `contains` method.  If none is found, return `false`.

```
override func isApplicableToList(list: [ShoppingItem]) -> Bool {
    //should return true if a dicount can be applied based on the supplied list of product ids (i.e. a product must be matched to an offer)

    for item in list {
        if applicableProductIds.contains(item.productId) {
            return true
        }
    }

    // didn't find one       
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It all makes sense now!

Comment: Or in one line: `return !list.filter({ applicableProductIds.contains($0.productId)  }).isEmpty`

Comment: Yes, @vadian that should do it.  Unlike the `for loop` though, it will check every item instead of stopping when it finds the first one.